# Error creating a GameServices object

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

When trying to authenticate the local user I see the next exception happening:

```
I/Unity   (11264):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 11/22/14 12:32:38 -05:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
I/Unity   (11264):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 11/22/14 12:32:38 -05:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
I/Unity   (11264):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 11/22/14 12:32:38 -05:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
I/Unity   (11264):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 11/22/14 12:32:38 -05:00 DEBUG: Creating real IPlayGamesClient

D/GamesUnitySDK(11264): Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK

I/Unity   (11264): InvalidOperationException: There was an error creating a GameServices object. Check for log errors from GamesNativeSDK
I/Unity   (11264):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.GameServicesBuilder.Build (GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PlatformConfiguration configRef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (11264):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.InitializeGameServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (11264):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (11264):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (11264):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
I/Unity   (11264):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Errors from GamesNativeSDK:

```
E/GamesNativeSDK(11264): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotContents: an exception occurred.
E/GamesNativeSDK(11264): Could not register one or more required Java classes.
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

I am using the latest build available at [Google Play Games plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity):

- [GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.10.unitypackage](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/current-build/GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.10.unitypackage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for future reference, @mrggl also said:

> The error referenced in the stack overflow thread is mostly caused by
>   an out of date version of the Google Play Services client library.
>   Make sure that you've updated to the most recent version, rerun
>   android setup in Google Play Games, and then try again.

Just in case the error prevails, [see the same issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/280)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/280 partially fixed this issue.

@mrggl said:

> This might be an issue with the fact that the current plugin has
>   transitive dependency on libc++_shared.so - that's the case, linking
>   against the standard libraries statically might fix this problem.
>
> I've committed a statically linked version of libgpg here:
>   https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/debug_libgpg/debug.
>   Overwrite the old versions of libgpg with these and see if that
>   addresses the issue!